# AsyncStatus, wait for Status completed or canceled

Tags: c#, winapi, asynchronous, uwp, winrt-async

I have a function to send an e-mail:

```
public async Task<bool>  ComposeEmail(string email, string subject)
{
  var emailMessage = new Windows.ApplicationModel.Email.EmailMessage();
  emailMessage.Body = String.Empty;

  var emailRecipient = new Email.EmailRecipient(email);
  emailMessage.To.Add(emailRecipient);
  emailMessage.Subject = subject;

  return EmailManager.ShowComposeNewEmailAsync(emailMessage).status == AsyncStatus.Completed;
}
```

According to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.foundation.iasyncinfo#Windows_Foundation_IAsyncInfo_Status), `Started` is not the final result.
**How can I wait for the result?**
I tried using `await` but then `ShowComposeNewEmailAsync` is returning void, and I can't get the Status.

I am following [this link here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/contacts-and-calendar/sending-email): which is using `async/await` but with this method there is no way to get the result

Comment: You can look at the documentation for how to call the method.  It doesn't return a task; it's an older model of asynchronous programming, rather than a Task based model.

Comment: Why you declare an async function when you want to run it sync? Just call Wait() and you're donne

Comment: @Servy, docs are not telling me much. I know it is returning an `IAsyncAction` , but I can't seem to find a way to `await` it

Comment: @Oscar, how can I know the results after calling `wait()`, I don't see a return value. Sorry for obvious questions it's my very first time with windows API.

Comment: @Mhd.Tahawi Forget it, if this is an old API and it's not returning Task then there's no Wait() method.

Comment: *How can I wait for the result?* - this is incompatible with asynchronous tag. you must not wait at all. when operation will be completed - your callback will be called with final result of operation. exactly in this callback you need do something, but not wait. this is general concept

Comment: @Oscar, there is an `asTask()` extension method, and I can call `wait` on the result of it.

Comment: @RbMm, this is part of a Xamarin project, I need to know if the user canceled the sending or not to know what I should do next. Usually I would use `async/await`, but not sure what is the alternative in this case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I ended up doing eventually.

```
public async Task<bool>  ComposeEmail(string email, string subject)
{
    var emailMessage = new Windows.ApplicationModel.Email.EmailMessage();
    emailMessage.Body = String.Empty;

    var emailRecipient = new  Email.EmailRecipient(email);
    emailMessage.To.Add(emailRecipient);
    emailMessage.Subject = subject;

    var x = (EmailManager.ShowComposeNewEmailAsync(emailMessage));

    await x; 
    return x.Status == AsyncStatus.Completed;
}
```

However, the result here is not whether the User has actually sent the email or not. it seems to be if the program was lunched correctly or not.

I am getting result completed even before sending or cancelling the Email.

Answer (score 1):

The API method's signature is:

```
public static IAsyncAction ShowComposeNewEmailAsync(EmailMessage message);
```

As you see, the `IAsyncAction` is generic result, that only informs the `await` that the action is complete, but does not carry any additional information - in this case does not inform you if the user actually sent the e-mail or not.

You can see this is the case if you compare it with `Launcher`'s `LaunchUriAsync` method for example:

```
public static IAsyncOperation<bool> LaunchUriAsync(Uri uri);
```

This one returns a `bool` that indicates if the launch was successful or not.

This means the built-in API does not support the functionality you require, it only creates mail message and prepares it for the user to send, but you cannot know if she actually sent it.

As an alternative you could present the user with a confirmation dialog, if he has sent the e-mail message or should the mail compose window be shown again.

var messageDialog = new MessageDialog("No internet connection has been found.");

```
var messageDialog = new MessageDialog( "Have you successfully sent the e-mail?" );    
messageDialog.Commands.Add(new UICommand(
    "Yes", 
    new UICommandInvokedHandler(YesHandler)));
messageDialog.Commands.Add(new UICommand(
    "Try again", 
    new UICommandInvokedHandler(TryAgainHandler)));  
await messageDialog.ShowAsync();
```

As a proof you can use the following snippet:

```
var action = EmailManager.ShowComposeNewEmailAsync(emailMessage);
await action;
Debug.WriteLine(action.Status);
```

The `Status` is always `Completed` once the mail app launches.

But it is true it is quite unfortunate a `bool` result of the action is not available. I think the reason is that any app can respond to the request, including older Win32 apps.

Comment: That's not 100% accurate. `IAsyncAction` inhertis from `IAsyncInfo` which has a `Status` field of type `AsyncStatus`. and that's what I am trying to reach :)

Comment: I know it has the `Status` field, but this field basically only reflects if the `async` action has finished, no matter which was the outcome. If you use `await` it will automatically "return" when the `Status` is `Completed`. The `Canceled` action is also not "user canceled", but "a thread stopped the asynchronous action"

Comment: yes I had misunderstood it. I just added that in my answer.
Thanks for clarifying. I was misguided by `Status.Started` so I assumed it waits for user to finish. too good to be true :)

Comment: I have just updated my answer with basically the same thing :-)

Comment: But it is true it is quite unfortunate a `bool` result of the action is not available. I think the reason is that any app can respond to the request, including older Win32 apps.